# What does the javadoc comment above package declaration do?

Tags: java, javadoc

When I create a new class in Eclipse and check "Generate comments", I get this:

```
/**
 *
 */
package my_package;

/**
 * @author myname
 *
 */
public class MyClass {

}
```

What's the point of the comment above the package declaration? It doesn't seem to be included anywhere (if I put something there) when I generate javadocs. Is it just Eclipse misfiring, or a weird Eclipse setting I have, or is it there for a reason?

Comment: If I do that in IntelliJ, it complains that it's "dangling" which is usually reserved for occasions when you've misplaced them. I've also never seen them used there before. So yes, this looks like Eclipse misfiring

Comment: It does a couple of things.  Some IDEs use that text as an on-hover text bubble when you're hovering over a commented item.  When you generate an actual javadoc, it uses that text in the description of the class, method, or field, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/uk/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#format)

> A doc comment is written in HTML and must precede a class, field,
> constructor or method declaration

There *are* also [package-level comments](https://www.oracle.com/uk/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#packagecomments) which are placed in a file called `package-info.java`, which are used for generating [documentation such as for the package `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Trying to include a package-level comment in a regular source file seems like a bug. [The docs state "you can place your comments in one of the following files..."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html). IntelliJ also shows the warning "Dangling Javadoc comment" when package-level comments are placed in a regular source file.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is only a convention. As far as I can tell, javadoc only processes package level javadoc from `package.html` or `package-info.java`. See ["Package Comment Files"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment) (this is for Java 7, but I couldn't find the equivalent for a newer Java version). And adding a package javadoc in any "normal" .java file will be ignored by the javadoc tool.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This is the 8 equivalent. It looks pretty much the same, though I only skimmed it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Comment: Thanks, to be honest, I only tried finding it in the Java 17 docs :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Anyway, thanks. That documentation seems conclusive enough. "*you can place your comments in one of the following files*" sort of implies that the list is exhaustive. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

For me, The comments generated above package are because of preference settings:

[image]

If I un-check `Automatically add comments for new methods, types, modules ,packages and files`, it is not appearing for me.

Moreover, if I edit `Files` comments, then File level comments are  not appearing whenever I generate comments.